# working in Docker with large datasets

Tags: docker, machine-learning, dataset, dockerfile

I have several Docker images that work with several big datasets. I like to think of the images as functions that take the datasets and output information.

Each image has to format the datasets before "consuming" them. I'm thinking I should do this formatting on the host before instancing the images.

Is there a tool that helps me manage these datasets? Or should I implement it myself?

Comment: I'm afraid this is far too vague to get a decent answer. Could you come up with specific problem?

Comment: You could have a container that formats your raw data and puts it in a volume which a second container connects to and process the formatted data. Still, I agree with @AdrianMouat, it's too vague as a question!